# R indirect reference in data frame

Tags: r

I would like to refer to values in a data frame column with the row index being dependent on the value of another column.

Example:

```
value   lag laggedValue
1        1      2
2        2      4
3        3      6
4        2      6
5        1      6
6        3      9
7        3      10
8        1      9
9        1      10
10       2
```

In Excel I use this formula in column "`laggedValue`":

```
=INDIRECT("B"&(ROW(B2)+C2))
```

How can I do this in an R data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explicitly specify what is column `B` and column `C`?

Comment: seems like you are just adding `value` and `lag`

Comment: Ok, sorry, I was in a hurry when posting the question. Column B is "value" C is "lag". laggedValue is not just the sum of value and lag, but an entry of column "value", lagged by the number of rows indicated in "lag". Stupid example, I agree. Should have been more specific. josilber got it right anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For row `r` with associated lag value `lag[r]` it looks like you're trying to create a new column that is the `(r+lag[r])`th element of `value` (or a missing value if this is out of bounds). You can do this with:

```
dat$laggedValue <- dat$value[seq(nrow(dat)) + dat$lag]
dat
   value lag laggedValue
1      1   1           2
2      2   2           4
3      3   3           6
4      4   2           6
5      5   1           6
6      6   3           9
7      7   3          10
8      8   1           9
9      9   1          10
10    10   2          NA
```

Other commenters are mentioning that it looks like you're just adding the `value` and `lag` columns because your `value` column has the elements 1 through 10, but this solution will work even when your `value` column has other data stored in it.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for for quite some time today. Will try it tomorrow with my real data. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same thing as [@rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr) here:

```
dat <- data.frame(value=c(1:10),
                  lag=c(1,2,3,2,1,3,3,1,1,2))

dat$laggedValue <- dat$value + dat$lag
dat
   value lag laggedValue
1      1   1           2
2      2   2           4
3      3   3           6
4      4   2           6
5      5   1           6
6      6   3           9
7      7   3          10
8      8   1           9
9      9   1          10
10    10   2          12
```